# Grails filters: can't make it work !

Tags: security, grails, filter

Im trying to write a Filter for my web-app. I read [the documentation][1], and wrote this dummy filter in my `grails-app/conf` directory

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       someFilter(controller:'*',action:'*') {

              write('Filtering')
           
       }
   }
}
```

Next thing I do is set a breakpoint on the `write` statement, but it just doesn't stop there.

Do I need to "register" this filter or anything? Spring may be bodering?

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255285/grails-filter-syntax-or-how-to-call-a-grails-filter-outside-grails), it doesn't look like it.

Maybe i'm doing something wrong, or overlooked anything?

## update

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {

       all(controller:'*',action:'*') {
        before={
              println 'Filtering'
              return false
        }
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[1]: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/single.html#6.6 Filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems. One is there's no 'write' method - change it to 'println' and it should work. But a filter is comprised of some combination of before, after, and afterView sub-closures, so what you really want is

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
      someFilter(controller:'*',action:'*') {
         before = {
            println 'Filtering'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But if you're really creating a security filter, please don't. It's too easy to do this incorrectly. The [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [Shiro](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro) plugins have plenty of features and are easy to configure and use.

Comment: Still nothing :( . On ss -core and shiro, i don't think they can do what I need, its highly dependant on data and my database structure. Something on the lines of "if this user belongs to this organization, then grant access"

Comment: i agree with Burt, you should use one of the existing plugins, they can be customize to utilize your own data structures

Comment: @Aaron All I see is ROLES and USERS, but nothing else :(

Comment: Ok, I got it working. Turns out that the class name was SecurityFilters, but the file name was SecurityFilter. Refactored the file and voila!. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom you can customize what user details are evaluated during the authentication process take a look at this http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Custom+UserDetailsService

Comment: You wouldn't want to use the Acegi plugin, it's basically deprecated since all work is being done on the Spring Security Core plugin and its extension plugins. See section 11 in http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/ for the custom UserDetailsService writeup. You can also easily create a custom AuthenticationProvider that provides a more low-level hook into the authentication process.